# Why Apache need to be compiled with openssl?

Tags: apache, mod-ssl

Why apache need to be compiled with openssl?
Does Apache copy files from openssl?
I need to update openssl vesion and I want to know if I also need to update the Apache version due to the change of the openssl vesion?

Comment: mod_ssl needs to be compiled with openssl dependency

Comment: What is exactly the openssl dependency?
If I compiled Apache with version X of openssl and now there is a security bug in openssl that openssl version Y solves, should I recompile Apache with version Y of openssl.
does the openssl version affects Apache in this case?

Comment: use [apxs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/apxs.html) tool to recompile single mod_ssl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is short, so I thought my comment would be enough. 
My reputation is too low to add a comment. 
Anyway, if you are using mod_ssl module which is provided by Apache, then you need to install it or as other commentator said you may use apxs.

If you see mod_ssl.so by ldd mod_ssl in modules direcotry under httpd. 
You may see something like below. 
ldd mod_ssl.so

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff823ff000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /PREFIX/openssl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fb3b32d4000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /PREFIX/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fb3b2e8c000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb3b2c3e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb3b28c7000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb3b26c2000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb3b377d000)
```

Some of libraries are linked to openssl library:libssl, libcrypto. 
However, you may not recompile your apache if u use third party mod_ssl which is compatible with apache module.